# Angular ui router load child state template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a stateConfig with a inheritance hierarchy as follows dep->chan->ying. However when i issue `$state.go('ying')` i see the url changing from `dep/opt` to `dep/opt/test` but the template `app/ying.html` doesn't load! How to get the template loaded on child state transition especially when the parent doesn't have abstract as true?

```
  function config ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('chan', {
        parent : 'dep',
        url : '/opt',
        params : {

        },
        reloadOnSearch : false,
        template : '<chan></chan>'
      })
      .state('ying', {
        parent : 'chan',
        url : '/test',
        templateUrl : '/app/ying.html',
        resolve : {
          access : access
        },
        onEnter : onEnter
      });

  }
```

Comment: I think you need add `<div ui-view></div>` inside `<chan></chan>` component template

Comment: yes that was the issue! it works now